# How to unmount a mech suit in Carrion

Tags: carrion

When controlling a human character, I know I can mount a mech suit using <kbd>space</kbd> button, fire gatling gun with LMB and aim crosshair with RMB. But I don't seem to find an option for unmounting.

I want to directly unmount a mech suit without severing the connection with the human.